# How can I determine if a post has an image attachment?

Tags: images, conditional-content

As far as I know, there's not a simple function that will return true if a post has an attachment. With that in mind, what's the best way to determine if a post has an attachment (or even better, has an image attachment)? I'm automatically inserting a shortcode on posts, but would like that to only happen if there is actually an image attached to the post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
$attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image') );

if ( $attachments ) {

 // do conditional stuff here 

}
```

Comment: Does it understand it without slash and image format identifier?