# Get images attached to a specific page

Tags: images, uploads, attachments, media, media-library

Is there a way to fetch the URLs and captions of all images attached to page *x*?

Comment: Something like this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/93961/21376 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$is = get_children("post_parent=$id&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image");
foreach($is as $i) {
  $url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($i->ID, 'full');
  $caption = $i->post_title);
}
```

$id is the id of your post. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children